# RadRotator problem in firefox 3.6 - Horizontal line appears when we hover on left or right buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, telerik, rotator

i am using firefox 3.6 & vs2010 asp.net empty application with c#...

i do not know what is going on about my radrotator in firefox? (In IE Every thing Is Ok)

when we hover on left or right buttons In RadRotator , a Horizontal line appears!

how can i fix this problem?

thanks for attention

Comment: you should put the solution as an answer or delete the question...

Comment: I Do That / Thanks For Attention... plz Accept My Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out this problem was about text-ident=-9999px; css of those buttons...